# Pass service to view model or leave thin controller as is

Tags: c#, mvc

I have the following action:

```
    public PartialViewResult Analyze()
    {
        var viewModel = new WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel
        {
            IsDrugsPanelVisible = !Service.IsMDStandalone(),
            IsDevicesPanelVisible = Service.IsSubscribedToMedTech(),
            IsCompaniesPanelVisible = !Service.IsCTStandalone(),
            IsCountriesPanelVisible = !Service.IsCTStandalone() || (Service.IsCTStandalone() && Service.HasImsAddOn()),
            IsFinancePanelVisible = !Service.IsCTStandalone()
        };

        return PartialView("Analyze", viewModel);
    }
```

I'm not sure if I should just pass the `Service` property to the constructor of the `WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel` or leave this code as is but from the perspective of a thin controller this doesn't feel right.

The `Service` property contains an object to a permission service (`IPermissionService`) which can be used for other applications outside of the web environment.

Would it be acceptable for one service to call another service, so for instance I create an `AnalyzeService` which contains methods with calls to `IPermissionService` methods?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a separate class for doing this processing and mapping.
It will be a service or mapper class takes your `Service` object in the constructor and has a method which return `WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel` object.

Also you can do it all through the method, by passing your `Service` object to this method and return the `WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel`, this will make your controller very thin something like that:

```
public PartialViewResult Analyze()
{
        var viewModel = Mapper.GetWelcomeAnalyzeViewModel(Service);
        return PartialView("Analyze", viewModel);
}

public class Mapper
{
  public WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel(ServiceType service)
  {
      return new WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel
        {
            IsDrugsPanelVisible = !Service.IsMDStandalone(),
            IsDevicesPanelVisible = Service.IsSubscribedToMedTech(),
            IsCompaniesPanelVisible = !Service.IsCTStandalone(),
            IsCountriesPanelVisible = !Service.IsCTStandalone() || (Service.IsCTStandalone() && Service.HasImsAddOn()),
            IsFinancePanelVisible = !Service.IsCTStandalone()
        };
  }
}
```

And i will put this mapper class in the `ViewModels` project if you have a separate project for them.

Comment: Which layer would the service be contained in then as it would only really apply to the presentation layer, but I thought services should be part of the application layer?

Comment: Is your Service just exist on the presentation layer, so this mapper class should be in the presentation layer as well

Comment: The `IPermissionService` is contained in the application layer.

Comment: and what about the ViewModels? if they are in the presentation layer so the mapper will be there as well.

Comment: Good point so this mapper really needs to reside in the presentation layer, is a mapper the correct term to use?

Comment: hmm, naming is your call, but it can be called ViewModelsBuilder ViewModelProcessor, something which construct view models.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the point of having thin controllers, but I feel like this belongs in the controller.

Imagine if your `ViewModels` were in a separate project than your controllers and your services as well. Would you want to create a dependance between the `ViewModels` DLL and the `Services` DLL? I don't think so.

The view models are basically DTO, they shouldn't have access to your services.

Though, I don't know if your service calls are expensive, but since you repeat some calls more than once, you might want to keep them in a variable. If they are expensive, you'll get a much better performance, if they ain't well... You'll get... less calls to your service!

```
public PartialViewResult Analyze()
{
    bool isCTStandAlone = Service.IsCTStandalone();
    var viewModel = new WelcomeAnalyzeViewModel
    {
        IsDrugsPanelVisible = !Service.IsMDStandalone(),
        IsDevicesPanelVisible = Service.IsSubscribedToMedTech(),
        IsCompaniesPanelVisible = !isCTStandAlone,
        IsCountriesPanelVisible = !isCTStandAlone || (isCTStandAlone && Service.HasImsAddOn()),
        IsFinancePanelVisible = !isCTStandAlone()
    };

    return PartialView("Analyze", viewModel);
}
```

I think it's a dangerous path to try and "thin" everything. At some point, some of your classes will hold more code than others. You want your controllers to be as thin as possible and that's good. That's why you have services, view models, etc. But building these things belong in the controller sometimes.